# How To Invoke Menu, Sub-Menu And Select/Deselect Options in Delphi XE?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

Is there any way that programatically we could invoke any menu and sub-menu option in Delphi XE ?

For Example, is it possible through Delphi program to invoke any Delphi project file and then invoke Tools menu, then get invoked 'Options...' sub-menu automatically and get selected/deselected any options as per requirement.

Comment: Specifically about options, maybe it is an option to parse/patch DPR files, they are XML in essence.

Comment: If this question is a follow-up of your previous question, then you should do something different. You should prepare target configurations for all the projects (they are stored in the XML format in *.dproj files) and build them with such configuration. That allows you to build even the project group with a given configuration (e.g. from command line). Once you have setup all the configurations for all your projects in the group, you can run `msbuild yourgroup.groupproj /t:Build /p:Configuration=Release` where `Release` is the build configuration.

Comment: You would do better if you asked about your problem rather than about your solution. Please also make up your mind about which version you target.

Comment: Keyboard macro can do that.

Comment: Ok, now I've seen your original question it's even more clear that you are going about this the wrong way.

Comment: @David Heffernan: I would like to learn how could I invoke menus and select/deselect the options. For compilation I already got the answer using Project Group. This invoking topic I would like to learn, if in future I need to do such things. Thank You.

Comment: Use one of the Automation APIs to automate applications

Answer (score 0):

The Delphi IDE has a published API that should explain how to accomplish your goal. See:

> [**Creating IDE Extensions with the Delphi Open Tools API -
>   Embarcadero
>   Technologies**](http://www.embarcadero.com/rad-in-action/otapi)

There is a good deal of material there on the Embarcadero website.